# NodeJS: Express server not responding to GET requests

Tags: node.js, express, server, centos7, firewall

I have a nodeJS server using express running on port X of machine A having IP address abc. When I search for 'http://abc:X/' in my browser, there is no response. cURL also does not respond.
Then I built a simple server without using express. This server responds to both browser and cURL.
Note that this express+nodeJS server was running fine on localhost, so there is no issue with the syntax.
What is the main issue here?

This is the server code:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
  res.send("Hello").status(200);
});
app.listen(5050, ()=>{
  console.log("Server is running");
});
```

When I run this file on machine A, "Server is running" gets printed. But the server does not respond to browser or cURL requests. I have checked the port as well as the connections, there is no issue. In fact, as I have mentioned, if I write the same server without express, everything works. If it is important, machine A uses centOS7, and node version 16.18.1.

Has it got something to do with Firewall settings? Does expressJS require some permissions which are not required by a nodeJS server written without expressJS?

Comment: Seems to work just fine when I try it. What request are you sending, and what response are you getting?

Comment: If I type http://abc:X/ on my browser, the browser keeps on waiting, until I stop the server

Comment: What is `abc:X`? Your app is listening on `localhost:5050`.

Comment: This was an example. abc is the IP of machine A. I am trying to connect to http://abc:5050/ from my pc

Comment: But have you actually tried `localhost:5050`?

Comment: That's the interesting part; if I ssh into machine A and do cURL GET for localhost:5050, it keeps on waiting until I stop the server. Running the server without using express works fine

Comment: The only thing you have that's incorrect is setting the status code after sending the response. Using `send()` without previously setting the status code will automatically set the code to 200. Is the code your using exactly what you posted or is this a slimmed down example?

Comment: Removing CORS,?  What happens?

Answer (score -2):

Look, I executed your code on my PC, and work normally. I saw that you are using a `node watch` to run your project and you are using node v16.18.1, but `node watch` just work with node v19+.

So try to update your node version and try again.

Comment: I haven't used `node watch`, what makes you think so?

Comment: Sorry was a mistake. But do you have the same problem yet?